# What is the intuition behind pseudogroups and why can they capture local symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, intuition, symmetry

What is the intuition behind pseudogroups and why can they capture local symmetry?

I read on Wikipedia that they can capture the notion of local symmetry. What does this mean exactly and how can they do it?

Comment: Do you understand why group actions capture symmetry and how open sets (or similar topological notions) help with locality? Is there a part of the definition of pseudo groups you are having trouble with? I'm not asking expecting particular answers, but this will help someone craft an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes I do to both of those questions. But I don’t really know what local symmetry even means.